# Here Maps SSL failure

Tags: javascript, html, maps, here-api

we need Here Maps to work with SSL, because our site uses only HTTPS. We try to load it using this url:

https://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all

But it still loads the content via http, is there anyway to fix that?

Please help us!

Thank you

Comment: Please consider adding your solution as an answer and marking it as the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an enterprise subscription of Here Maps to retrieve the maps in SSL. Then you can accomplish a secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code example from the [Enterprise JavaScript API Explorer](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/enterprise-api-explorer). This line of code enables SSL:

```
(document.location.protocol == "https:") && nokia.Settings.set("secureConnection", "force");
```

But for me it's still loading graphic map tiles in http:

For more info read this [forum thread](http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/233641-Does-the-API-work-with-SSL-or-HTTPS).